# How do i solve the NullErrorException

Tags: java

Hie i am trying to implement the offside rule in the simplesoccer game by matt buckland.I have a method in the soccer team class which calculates the closest player to own goal and returns that player.I have another method in the `PlayerBase` which checks if this player is ahead of a defender by using the method in the SoccerTeam.I have another method in `PlayerBase` which returns `true` or `false` if this player is offside
when i try to run the code it gives the `nullpointer exception`
Here are the codes

```
 //calculate the player closest to own goal and return the player's position
public PlayerBase CalculateClosestPlayerToOwnGoal() {
    double ClosestSoFar = MaxFloat;

    ListIterator<PlayerBase> it = m_Players.listIterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        PlayerBase cur = it.next();
        if(!cur.isGoalKeeper()){
        //calculate the dist. Use the squared value to avoid sqrt
        double dist = Vec2DDistanceSq(cur.Pos(), m_pHomeGoal.Center());

        //keep a record of this value for each player
        //cur.SetDistToOwnGoal(dist);

        if (dist < ClosestSoFar) {
            ClosestSoFar = dist;

            m_pPlayerClosestToOwnGoal = cur;

        }
        }
    }
    return m_pPlayerClosestToOwnGoal;
}

public boolean IsAheadOfDefender(){
        if( abs(this.Pos().x - Team().OpponentsGoal().Center().x)
            < abs(Team().Opponents().CalculateClosestPlayerToOwnGoal().Pos().x -         Team().OpponentsGoal().Center().x)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at Nhabvu.PlayerBase.IsAheadOfDefender(PlayerBase.java:272)
at Nhabvu.PlayerBase.isOffSide(PlayerBase.java:281) 
at Nhabvu.SoccerTeam.TeamMemberIsOffSide(SoccerTeam.java:780)
at Nhabvu.SoccerPitch.Update(SoccerPitch.java:200)
at Nhabvu.Main.main(Main.java:161)
```

Comment: You are calling a very large number of methods in the first line of `IsAheadOfDefender()`. Try to split it up a bit by declaring some intermediate variables, then it should be easier to find out which method is returning null and hence causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: There is a lot of code that you haven't shown us here - all those method calls, any of which could be returning null, and causing the NPE.  But we won't know which method call is to blame, until you show us all of your code.  Also, I have an odd feeling that you don't understand the offside rule, although that's not a Java issue.

Comment: a player is in offside position if he is nearer to the goal line than the defender(ahead of the defender). if a pass is made to the player in that position then its an offside. basically thats the logic. i understand the offside rule

Comment: i tried introducing intermediate variables and the method giving the error is the CalculateClosestPlayerToOwnGoal

Comment: If you understand the offside rule, then why are you calculating the distance to the goal itself, instead of the goal line?  The distance to the goal itself is completely irrelevant.  You could just look at the X co-ordinate of the player, and all of the opponents, and save yourself a whole lot of calculation.  The only thing you need to calculate is - of all 11 of my opponents, how many have an X coordinate greater than mine, and how many have an X coordinate less than mine.  It also makes no difference whether a player is the goalkeeper, so there's no point in calling `isGoalKeeper` at all.

Answer (score -3):

paste this in try-catch block

```
  if( abs(this.Pos().x - Team().OpponentsGoal().Center().x)
            < abs(Team().Opponents().CalculateClosestPlayerToOwnGoal().Pos().x -         Team().OpponentsGoal().Center().x)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Is "have lots of sticking plasters handy" a good answer to "how do I avoid cutting my finger when I chop vegetables?"